# Why Firebird access to joined tables in a simple count?

Tags: firebird

I have view like:

```
SELECT F1, F2
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T2.ID=T1.ID
LEFT JOIN T3 ON T3.ID=T1.ID
```

When I do a count query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYVIEW
```

If T1 has 1000 records, Firebird generates 3000 accesses to records: 1000 for T1, 1000 for T2, 1000 for T3.

Is there a way to optimize it? I could use the directly the table:
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1

but I need to use the views, I cannot use tables. Well, the problem is more complicated, but I have used this simple example to illustrate the basis problem. Firebird does not seem to optimize some queries and my question is if I can optimize the query changing something in the DDL of the view.

Comment: The LEFT JOINs should result in *less* than 3000 being returned (i.e. 1000 at most). The result is different than 3 separate counts on 3 separate tables. If the LEFT JOINs are causing poor performance, check the indices and query plan.

Comment: @user2864740 afaik op is referring to the read statistics, not the count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `JOIN` from `T1` to `T2` (and `T3`) can lead to more records than just those in `T1`. Say that for each record in `T1` there are two records in `T2`, then for 1000 records in `T1` the result of the count is 2000.

In theory the optimizer could know that `T1.ID` and `T2.ID` are both primary keys (or unique) and therefor only scan `T1`, but the optimizer in Firebird is not very advanced, so maybe it simply can't do that.